# How do I subscribe to PropertyChanged event in my ViewModel?

Tags: c#, mvvm, inotifypropertychanged

I have core functionality encapsulated in `ViewModelBase`

Now I want to see when PropertyChanged event was raised by ViewModelBase and act on it. For example, when one property was changed on ViewModelBase  - I want to change property on my ViewModel

How do I achieve this?

```
public class MaintainGroupViewModel : BaseViewModel<MEMGroup>
    {


public abstract class BaseViewModel<T> : NotificationObject, INavigationAware
        where T : Entity
    {
```

Comment: Does your `NotificationObject` implement `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface? If so, then it is basic event subscription. If not then you should implement `INotifyPropertyChanged`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

I am concerned that you're effectively doing a 'manual binding' (bad) for a property in a derived class to a value on the base class (also bad).  The whole point of using inheritance is that the derived class can access things in the base class.  Use a `protected` modifier to indicate things should only be accessible to derived classes.

I would suggest this (potentially) more correct method:

Base class:

```
protected virtual void OnMyValueChanged() { }
```

Derived class:

```
protected override void OnMyValueChanged() { /* respond here */ }
```

Really, subscribing to an event in the base class of the very class you're writing just seems incredibly backwards - what's the point of using inheritance over composition if you're going to compose yourself around yourself?  You're literally asking an object to tell itself when something happens.  A method call is what you should use for that.

In terms of *"when one property was changed on ViewModelBase - I want to change property on my ViewModel"*, ... they are the same object!

Comment: Yes, it does smell :) My scenario is like this... I have base functionality but in this specific case I want to rearrange some of the data on my ViewModel when some base data changed. Base class maintains main data entity (let's say Customer) and I want to update more UI when Customer changes.

Comment: I would still suggest using methods rather than events, and using composition over inheritance if necessary: create a new object which contains the base ViewModel.  Otherwise everyone will still have access to the 'base' functionality of the base ViewModel, which actually you seem to be modifying, so a derived class doesn't fit.

Comment: Maybe method is a way to go. Another example. Base class maintains "state" of my data entry form. Like NEW, EDIT, ADD. Bunch of UI binds to this state. In my VM, I want to know about this state change as well. I can create method OnStateChange or I can subscribe to PropertyChanged. Do you see need to recompose or just create methods? Methods might be "cleaner" to look at

Comment: That functionality would belong in the base view model - especially something as generic as OnStateChange.  Can you give another example? :)

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of functionality in BaseVM. But same OnStateChange might be needed in VM. Let's say I want to reset lookup list when new record being created. I need to know when state changes and do this.

Comment: As I said OnStateChange would belong either in the base VM.  If the base VM isn't appropriate, then you'd create a VM to represent the view that needs the new functionality.  The 'inner VM' holding the data would be a property on and component of the new VM.  The new VM might then subscribe to events.  That's composition though, inheritance simply doesn't work based on what you're saying..

Comment: I got it. Basically, subscribing to own events is a code smell. Overriding OnStateChange and calling base.OnStateChange is a proper way to handle this scenario. Both kind of achieve same functionality.

Comment: @katit: This is how the framework, er, works.  Check out many of the events in various framework classes.  You'll see that they have "On[EventName]" virtual methods you can override to interact with the raising of the event.  There's more to it, of course...

Answer (score 84):

Usually I use register to the `PropertyChanged` event in the class Constructor

```
public MyViewModel()
{
    this.PropertyChanged += MyViewModel_PropertyChanged;
}
```

and my PropertyChanged event handler looks like this:

```
void MyViewModel_PropertyChanged(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    switch (e.PropertyName)
    {
        case "SomeProperty":
            // Do something
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there anyway to get rid of "magic-strings" while handling. (I am not using C# 6)

Comment: @Marshal I'm not sure, what about [this blog post by Josh Smith](https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/one-way-to-avoid-messy-propertychanged-event-handling/)?

Comment: I think that's a good solution, and testable enough. Thanks for pointing to the article.

Comment: @Rachel: What do you think about using this technique to also avoid "Duplicate RaisePropertyChanged for Cascading Read-Only Properties"  ("https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46314677/avoiding-duplicate-raisepropertychanged-for-cascading-read-only-properties")?

Comment: @Tom I think it's fine. Left you an answer to your question to :)

Answer (score 2):

The direct way to subscribe to property changes is using [`INotifyPropertyChanged`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.inotifypropertychanged.propertychanged.aspx) if your `BaseViewModel` implements it:

```
PropertyChanged += (obj, args) =>
   { System.Console.WriteLine("Property " + args.PropertyName + " changed"); }
```

If it doesn't, then it has to be a `DependencyObject`, and your properties have to be `DependencyProperties` (which is probably a more complicated way).

[This article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/llobo/archive/2007/03/05/listening-to-dependencyproperty-changes.aspx) describes how to subscribe for `DependencyProperty` changes.