# Passing month parameter from binded datepicker to linq method MVVM EF

Tags: c#, wpf, entity-framework, linq, mvvm

I am looking for a way to pass the selected month from the date picker to my query in order to make the query dynamic. How do I replace the **9** with the month binded to the datepicker? I was thinking of something along the lines of  ***a.sMonth = DateTime.Month(MDate))*** but it doesn't work. Simple suggestions are more than welcome. Thank you!

PS: the sMonth from the table is long.

```
namespace Location.ViewModel
{
    public class LocationViewModel: INotifyPropertyChanged
    {


        public LocationViewModel()
        {
            var db = new DailyEntities();
            Efficiency = Convert.ToDecimal(db.LocationKPI.Where(a => a.sMonth == 9).Select(a => a.Efficiency).FirstOrDefault());
        }

        private DateTime _mDate = DateTime.Now;

        public DateTime MDate
        {
            get { return _mDate; }
            set { _mDate = value; OnPropertyChanged("MDate"); }
        }

        decimal efficiency;

        public decimal Efficiency
        {
            get { return efficiency; }
            set
            {
                efficiency = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("Efficiency");
            }
        }


        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

        protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName = null)
        {
            if (PropertyChanged != null) PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried DateTime.ToString("MM") ?

Comment: Yes I did and I couldn't get it to work. Can you show me how would you do it in for this example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following code will get the number 9 from today's date which is the 30th September.

```
        var MDate = new DateTime();
        MDate = DateTime.Now;

        var month = 0;

        int.TryParse(MDate.ToString("MM"), out month);
```

I've used the MDate variable name so that it fits your existing code so you can ignore the first two lines.

`DateTime.ToString("MM")` gets the month in the format "09" but if we try to compare it with the integer 9, that integer will be implicitly converted into a string "9". Since "9" and "09" do not match, we have to convert "09" into an integer. `int.TryParse()` is the safest way to do this.

Now you have the month in a variable, you can use it in your query.

```
    public LocationViewModel()
    {
        var db = new DailyEntities();

        // Get the month from the date picker
        var month = 0;
        int.TryParse(MDate.ToString("MM"), out month);

        Efficiency = Convert.ToDecimal(db.LocationKPI.Where(a => a.sMonth == month).Select(a => a.Efficiency).FirstOrDefault());
    }
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This is exactly what I was looking for. Since the MDate is binded to my datepicker I was hoping that Efficiency would change if I changed the date to August but it doesn't. It only shows the current. Do you have any suggestions? What I am doing wrong is this example? That would really help me out.

Comment: @iCosmin Try this thread https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7824967/how-do-i-subscribe-to-propertychanged-event-in-my-viewmodel

Comment: @iCosmin Also try this https://joshsmithonwpf.wordpress.com/2009/07/11/one-way-to-avoid-messy-propertychanged-event-handling/

Comment: Thank you for the links. I feel like my head is about to explode. Is there an easier way? I am a just rookie when it comes to wpf and mvvm. Can you please show me how based on what I have?

Comment: @iCosmin I'm afraid I don't know WPF either, I would post another question.